# Undo , redo , delete for selected image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Hi i have an image upload form , and when selecting upload the image it will show the preview also.

```js
$( function() {

        var inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("user_file");
        inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change",previewImages,false);

        function previewImages(){
            var fileList = this.files;

            var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
                  var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
                  $('.new-multiple').append('<div class="img-div"><img src="' + objectUrl + '" class="newly-added" /></div>');
                  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
                }

               $( ".img-div" ).draggable();
              $( ".img-div" ).resizable();
              } 
});
```

```css
.new-multiple{
  width:400px !important;
  height:400px !important;
  background:white;
  border:2px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
  
 .img-div{
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
 } 
 .newly-added{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input   name="user_file[]" id="user_file" style="position: relative;overflow: hidden" multiple="" type="file">

 <div class="new-multiple"></div>
```

I write both resizable, draggable function for the images .

But is there any way

(1) when  i click on one image it will appear as selected [ may be an extra shadow for the selected , also clicking outside shadow disappear ] and

(2)when i press delete button in keyboard then selected image is deleted . When i press undo button then it will appear back ?

Please help.

> UPDATE

```
 .img-selected{
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px 6px rgb(206, 206, 206);
}



 $(".newly-added").on("click", function(e) {
       $(".newly-added").removeClass("img-selected");
       $(this).addClass("img-selected");
        e.stopPropagation()
    });
      $(document).on("click", function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).is(".newly-added") === false) {
          $(".newly-added").removeClass("img-selected");
        }
      });
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way. You have to write the code.

Comment: I got solution for first

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I added this jquery code

```
$(document).on('click','img',function(){
          $('img').removeClass('shadow'); 
          $(this).toggleClass("shadow");
       });
```

and the shadow css

```
.shadow{
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
      }
```

```js
$( function() {

        var inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("user_file");
        inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change",previewImages,false);

        function previewImages(){
            var fileList = this.files;

            var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
                  var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
                  $('.new-multiple').append('<div class="img-div"><img src="' + objectUrl + '" class="newly-added" /></div>');
                  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
                }

               $( ".img-div" ).draggable();
              $( ".img-div" ).resizable();
              } 
  $(document).on('click','img',function(){
      $('img').removeClass('shadow'); 
      $(this).toggleClass("shadow");
   });
});
```

```css
.new-multiple{
  width:400px !important;
  height:400px !important;
  background:white;
  border:2px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
  .shadow{
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  }
 .img-div{
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
 } 
 .newly-added{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input name="user_file[]" id="user_file" style="position: relative;overflow: hidden" multiple="" type="file">

 <div class="new-multiple"></div>
```