# Detect Keyboard keys and add function for this using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

Hi i have an image upload form , and when selecting upload the image it will show the preview also.

```js
$( function() {
  var inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("user_file");
  inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change",previewImages,false);
  function previewImages(){
    var fileList = this.files;
    var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
      var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
      $('.new-multiple').append('<div class="img-div"><img src="' + objectUrl + '" class="newly-added" /></div>');
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
    }

    $( ".img-div" ).draggable();
    $( ".img-div" ).resizable();
    $(".newly-added").on("click", function(e) {
      $(".newly-added").removeClass("img-selected");
      $(this).addClass("img-selected");
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).on("click", function(e) {
      if ($(e.target).is(".newly-added") === false) {
        $(".newly-added").removeClass("img-selected");
      }
    });
  } 
});
```

```css
.new-multiple {
  width:400px !important;
  height:400px !important;
  background:white;
  border:2px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
}
  
.img-div {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
} 

.newly-added {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
} 

.img-selected{
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px 6px rgb(206, 206, 206);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input   name="user_file[]" id="user_file" style="position: relative;overflow: hidden" multiple="" type="file">
<div class="new-multiple"></div>
```

I write both resizable, draggable function for the images .

so here when I click on selected img and press delete button on keyboard I  need to delete that image . If  press undo through keyboard I have to get it back . How can I achieve this

I see jQuery. Hotkeys ,  https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

and I write the following code . but it is not working

```
$('.img-selected').bind('del', '$', function(){
  alert("yes");
});
```

Please check this

https://jsfiddle.net/vd11qyzv/7/

> UPDATED FIDDLE

Please check this  https://jsfiddle.net/vd11qyzv/9/ . Here

`if ($(e.target).is(".newly-added") === true) { alert('abc'); }` is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undo , redo , delete for selected image using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520398/undo-redo-delete-for-selected-image-using-jquery)

Comment: It's an hour ago since you created an almost identical question, just because someone hasn't been able to provide an answer yet, then you should wait a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard event is not going to img-selected object.
Until now for keyboard handling I used this format and worked well.

```
$(document).on('keydown', handleKeyDown);

function handleKeyDown(e){

    if(e.keyCode === 46)//delete Key{
    deleteActiveObject();
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i will check this .Thank you .  But from where you got this e.keyCode === 46

Comment: You can check easily `console.log(e.keyCode)`

Comment: for some reason it is not working . Could you please provide an example. Try my code in https://jsfiddle.net/vd11qyzv/7/

Comment: but what i want is https://jsfiddle.net/vd11qyzv/9/ . please check here .$(e.target).is(".newly-added") === true this is important . Why this code not working

Comment: You cannot work with e.target because key event is captured on document so e.target is 'body'. See this https://jsfiddle.net/vd11qyzv/10/